# Wpf - Stretch ItemControl horizontaly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the below xaml, and I want the items in the itemsControl to stretch and always touch the left and the rigth of the window. I tried `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` in the `ScrollViewer` or/and `ItemsControl`

```
<Window x:Class="myClass"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="myTitle"
    Height="300" Width="300" 
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue" Width="300">
        <ItemsControl Name="myItemControl" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding myItemList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="15" />
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Hello, coucou, reprenons contact. Anben

Comment: Anben ca fait un bail, je t'ai envoye un email. Celle qui contient le nom de ton groupe de police prefere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Grid` object nicely fills up your `ItemsControl`.  However, if you want the actual contents (`Id` and `Name`) to touch the left *and* right sides, you need to align the second `TextBlock` to the right. By default, a `TextBlock` control is aligned to the left.

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

The `Stretch` option will only take you so far.  It won't actually stretch the text in a `TextBlock`, because that would create deformed text; not the effect that most people intend.  That's where the left and right alignment of your actual content comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

Your stretches are on the ItemsControl which is going to stretch the ItemsControl, not the items. If you want to stretch the items, you need to stretch the Grid in the ItemTemplate.